# JQuery SmoothDivScroll and arrow keys

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I need to make JQuery [SmoothDivScroll plugin](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) works with arrow keyboard keys - left and right keys should scroll the content, as mouse wheels and hot spots do. How can I achieve this, using custom JQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it. Solution isn't pretty, but works. Moreover, code snippet should be moved to separate code file. TODO: refactor.

1) "scrollableArea" div should have attribute *tabindex*.
2) In plugin code file, below code statement should be added to *_create* function. It should be refactored, because currently it is considerably copied from *mousewheel* event handler

```
r.data("scrollableArea").keydown(function (e) {

            var arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };
            var i,s,u;

            switch (e.keyCode || e.which) {

                case arrow.left:
                    i = 1;
                    s = 0;
                    u = 1;
                    break;

                case arrow.right:
                    i = -1;
                    s = 0;
                    u = -1;
                    break;
            }

                if (r.data("enabled") && n.mousewheelScrolling.length > 0) {
                    var a;
                    n.mousewheelScrolling === "vertical" && u !== 0 ? (t.stopAutoScrolling(), e.preventDefault(), a = Math.round(n.mousewheelScrollingStep * u * -1), t.move(a)) :
                    n.mousewheelScrolling === "horizontal" && s !== 0 ? (t.stopAutoScrolling(), e.preventDefault(), a = Math.round(n.mousewheelScrollingStep * s * -1), t.move(a)) :
                        n.mousewheelScrolling === "allDirections" && (t.stopAutoScrolling(), e.preventDefault(), a = Math.round(n.mousewheelScrollingStep * i * -1), t.move(a));
                }
            }),
```

Comment: The purpose of an answer is to actually answer the question. The question isn't the place to put the solution of the question. So, instead, remove answer from your question and write it down in this answer.